# PHP Mysql laravel 5.4 terminal issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, command-line, wamp

i am new to laravel i just figured out how to install composer laravel etc etc on my local machine MAMP on windows , Now i am confuse with the command on terminal which is

```
 C:\project>mysql -uroot -proot
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: mysql client is not installed globally. Either install mysql client directly from the website or add a path variable pointing to the directory of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setting Environment will solve the issue

1. Go to `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced`
2. Click -  `Environment Variables`
3. Go to- System Variables find PATH and click on it.
4. add the path to your `mysql\bin` folder to the end  paths. (ex: `E:\xampp\mysql\bin`) and add `;` end of the line
5. Close all the command prompts you opens.
6. Re open and try it.

Comment: after step 3 can you explain more double click on path or single click and then click new on path etc and which file should i locate in my mamp/bin/mysql ??

Comment: ya. mysql bin path

Comment: i double click on path , and added new path with this line   

C:\MAMP\bin\mysql      is it ok ?

Comment: Thank you for the help let me fix the another error ty

Comment: @HassamAliQazalbash happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the PATH to point to the MYSQL bin folder is normally the first thought, but I find that dangerous as things get left lying around when you change software.

I normally create a little batch file in the projects folder or in a folder that it already on your PATH, like this

mysqlpath.cmd

```
echo off
PATH=C:\mamp\path\to\the\mysql\bin;%PATH%
mysql -v
```

The `mysql -v` will output the mysql version number but it is a handy way of knowing that the correct folder has been added to the PATH. This adds the folder to the PATH but only for the life of the command window.

Then just run this from any command window when you want to use MYSQL from the command line

```
> phppath
```

You may also like to create one for PHP as well

phppath.cmd

```
echo off
PATH=C:\mamp\path\to\the\php\;%PATH%
php -v
```